# how to define intents and entities on IBM watson conversation with Node.js app?

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, chatbot, watson-conversation, watson-assistant

I have made a chatbot on IBM WC and now I have a Node.js application from which I want to design a chatbot on Watson Conversation.

Is there a way I can set my intents and entities with some API through my Node app?

What is the best way to do this? Is this doable and what maybe the best approach to do this with Node.js?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Do you want to set intents and entities within the conversation message, or to build your workspace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the Watson Conversation API documentation for Node.Js - https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/node.html?node , based on NPM package "watson-developer-cloud". There are methods and examples for creating workspace/entities/intents directly from your code, after you defined the WCS service in your bluemix account.

Comment: Thanks a lot this helped !

Answer (score 1):

There is a [SDK for Node.js](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk) that you can use with Watson Assistant (formerly Watson Conversation). It supports the [API](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/assistant/api/v1/node.html?node) to retrieve and create intents and entities.

About a year ago I wrote an "[Egobot](https://github.com/data-henrik/bluemix-egobot)" in Python that dynamically, based on the dialog, extends a conversation workspace.  It is using the same API, though it is a different programming language. The same is used by this [CLI tool](https://github.com/data-henrik/watson-conversation-tool) to retrieve entire workspaces and to interact with the different objects (intents, entities, ...).

Comment: Thanks a lot this helped !